# Как перевести текст в число (для калькулятора)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

На Delphi чтобы перевести текст в число использовали:

```
c:= (strtofloat(edit1.text)) + (strtofloat(edit2.text))
```

А как это будет выглядеть для  в Visual C++ 2010? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
  float f;
  char *str = "12345.67";

  f = atof(str) + atof("3.1415926");
```

Если С++Builder, то

```
double c = StrToFloat(Edit1->Text) + StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
```

Comment: BuilderC, можешь написать мне код вот данного случая: 

вот у меня там 3 текстбокса, хочу на 2ух прибавить и ответ чтоб вышел на 3ем ... ну вот как написать чтобы какая то переменная например с вывел ответ, на дельфи знаю, а вот си нет, там было так:

c:= (strtofloat(edit1.text)) + (strtofloat(edit2.text)) где то так, а на си если не трудно напиши мне пожалуйста

Comment: Edit3->Text = FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1->Text) + StrToFloat(Edit2->Text));

Comment: выдает следующие ошибки:

1)К указателю должен быть применен оператор "*" или "->"
2)Элемент "FloatToStr" и "StrToFloat" не существует в текущем контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать потоки ввода вывода:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

{
    ...
    string s;
    ...
    std::stringstream stream(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
    stream << s;
    float f;
    stream >> f;
    ...
}
```

Comment: можешь написать мне код вот данного случая:
вот у меня там 3 текстбокса, хочу на 2ух прибавить и ответ чтоб вышел на 3ем ... ну вот как написать чтобы какая то переменная например с вывел ответ, на дельфи знаю, а вот си нет, там было так:
c:= (strtofloat(edit1.text)) + (strtofloat(edit2.text)) где то так, а на си если не трудно напиши мне пожалуйста

Comment: Напишите свою функцию `strtofloat` одним из предложенных способов.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй написать сам.

```
char conv(char c)
{
    return c - '0';
}  

string conv(string s)
{  
    string str;  
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.size(); i++)  
        str += conv(s[i]);  
    return str;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: shurik, можно поподробней? как будет выглядеть он вот в этой форме:

c:= (strtofloat(edit1.text)) + (strtofloat(edit2.text)) ?

Comment: atoi переводит из строки в int, а здесь нужно в float (strtofloat указан в качестве примера).

Comment: mikillskegg, ты не знаешь как?

Comment: stdlib.h

double atof (char *)