# Функции перевода типов данных С++

Tags: c++

Какие существуют функции перевода из одного типа данных в другой. А именно, интересуют:

1. из `char` в `int` и обратно,
2. из `string` в `int` и обратно,
3. из `char` в `string`,
4. из `double` в `int` и обратно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Зависит от того, что Вы имеете ввиду.

   ```
   char c1 = '7';
   int digit = c - '0';
   char c2 = 'S';
   int alphabet_position = c2 - 'A';
   ```
2. стандартные функции [`atoi`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) (из `char*` в `int`) и [`itoa`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) (из `int` в char*). Проблема рассмотрена в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/57411).
3. У [`string`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) есть конструктор `string(size_t n, char c)`, который создает строку, состоящую из `n` символов `c`.
4. Простое присваивание. Не забывайте про потерю точности. Есть функции округления [`floor(x)`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/) и [`ceil(x)`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/)  — наибольшее целое не больше `x` и наименьшее целое не меньше `x` соответственно. Также можно использовать [`static_cast`](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

*PS Почитайте в каком-нибудь справочнике про приведение типов.*

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант посмотрите в сторону stringstream.

Comment: Про то как этим воспользоваться можно прочитать в [этом](http://hashcode.ru/questions/57411) вопросе

Answer (score 0):

В качестве дополнения к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/61360/552) пользователя [@andrybak](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/202/andrybak).

В С++11 появилось семейство функций [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), которые могут конвертиртировать многие стандартные числовые типы в std::string.

Также были добавлены функции [std::sto{i,l,ll}](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), [std::stou{l,ll}](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul), [std::sto{f,d,ld}](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), которые производят обратную операцию.